# Manga where the main character gets reincarnated by another god and becomes bodyguard of a girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character, after being reincarnated into another world, hides his power but soon he is hired by a girl as a bodyguard in his class. Also he forms a contract with a poor god. He fights goddess of war in it. He also has a big sister who is quite powerful and is a sword saint or something like that. He also fights Fenrir in this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  You say he "forms a contract with a poor good."  Do you mean "poor god?"

Comment: yes my bad poor god.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[I Think I'll Hide My True Ability to the Last Moment.](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shin-no-jitsuryoku-wa-girigiri-made-kakushite-iyou-to-omou)*.

> A world where you can contract with God and gain skills. Born as the third son of a famous knight family, Yuno was so busy controlling his innate power that he was eventually called "incompetent." However, in the magical knight academy, who was enrolled for some reason, he fulfilled his fateful encounter with an unnamed god who was despised as "incompetent" like himself. Yuno, who contracted with the goddess and named her Athena, secretly decided to make her the highest god, and decided to get a little more serious.

I don't believe the main character is reincarnated; instead he met with an unknown (in their world) god named Zeus as a baby and obtained significant power. In the flashback of the first chapter it's shown that he intentionally hides his powers and that he has already a covenant with a god.

The "poor god" is an unnamed goddess that has been in the academy and unable to form a covenant with anyone. Yuno decides to form a covenant with her to strengthen her and gives her the name Athena.

[image: Unnamed goddess]

His sister is referred to as a sword saintess. She's a minor character so I don't have a screenshot of this handy. But everyone in Yuno's family except Yuno is considered exceptionally talented.

Fenrir also shows up; he does not exactly fight with Fenrir. This covers an entire arc so it's a bit difficult to summarize but it does happen.